# AWS EventBridge Event Format Different Between UI and CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to troubleshoot an EventBridge rule.  I can invoke an EventBridge event just fine from the CLI, but my rule is not picking up the event. When I try and copy / paste my event into the UI, it says it's not validly formatted. I notice that the CLI requires proper case keys and the UI requires lower case keys. What am I missing?

EventBridge UI documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ev-events.html

EventBridge CLI Put documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-events.html

I've tried each format, and they work in isolation, but I'm hoping to use them together to troubleshoot my rule issue.

Comment: Can you please share both CLI and UI request to help further?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal The requests are too long to put in this reply.  However, if I take one of the requests from the UI documentation above, and I put them in a test_event.json file, and try to submit that same request via the CLI, then I get this error:
```Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in Entries[0]: "version", must be one of: Time, Source, Resources, DetailType, Detail, EventBusName, TraceHeader
Unknown parameter in Entries[0]: "id", must be one of: Time, Source, Resources, DetailType, Detail, EventBusName, TraceHeader
```

Comment: The 2 pieces of documentation seem to contradict each other on the JSON key names / format.

Comment: You can put your request and response in the question and this is good practice to keep all details while asking question